# ios facebook login address invalid

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook-login

I used the sessionloginsample from facebook SDK as baseline. I changed the app ID and managed to authorise my fb acc with my App Name. However once i click the top okay button, a pop up states " cannot open page " because address is invalid. Does anyone know about the solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because you have not changed app ID in plist file of your application. You should change your app id in plist too. Put your app ID where I have written YOURAPPID, and it will be working. Check image attached for more clarification.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jennis it was done, and already authorized. The okay button I mentioned was on the authorization page top right corner.

Comment: Please mark as accepted and/or upvote if my answer helped you. So any other person searching for the same issue will have definite solution.